# Best way to ramp down in Jmeter?

Tags: performance, multithreading, jmeter

We all know Jmeter isn't the best at changing the number of active threads during the run (unless you get fancy and make separate thread groups that fire off at different intervals).

Has any come up with a good solution for ramping down at the end of the test?

For example, I start with 50 threads and within 30 minutes I want 0 active threads.

Comment: +1 for the question. http://osdir.com/ml/jakarta.jmeter.user/2004-06/msg00131.html suggests the answer is as you've described.

Comment: Thanks for the link....I think that would work nicely, especially if you created one thread group with the source code and put module controllers in the other groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Ultimate Thread Group [here](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/), I think this is it.